# XML element occurrence

Tags: xml, xsd

I am writing a schema for the following XML. I want to limit the occurrence of Element_E, Element_F and Element_G to '1' and Element_D can occur n number of times. I tried to use `xs:sequence` but it enforces the element order, `xs:choice` does not check the max occurrences of above elements.

Is it possible to validate the occurrence of each element in a group through XML Schema?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element_A>                     <!-- One time occurrence -->
  <Element_B>                   <!-- One time occurrence -->
    <Element_C>                 <!-- One time occurrence -->
      <Element_D />             <!-- n time occurrence -->
      <Element_D />
      <Element_D />
      <Element_E />             <!-- One time occurrence -->
      <Element_F />             <!-- One time occurrence -->
      <Element_G />             <!-- One time occurrence -->
    </Element_C>
  </Element_B>
</Element_A>
```

Comment: (1) Do you want `Element_D` to appear a constant number of times or an unlimited number of times?   (2) Must the occurrences be allowed to be interspersed with its siblings, or may they be limited to preceding all siblings as shown in your sample XML?

Comment: (1) Element_D can occur unlimited number of times.(2) Element_D can appear only under Element_C, nowhere else.

Comment: (2) But do you wish to allow E D D F D G, or is D D D E F G sufficient?

Comment: The Elements D,E,F and G can occur in any order. But E,F and G must appear only one time and D can appear unlimited number of times.

Comment: With XSD 1.0, you'll have to check that in code; with XSD 1.1 you can use `xs:assert` to state a count invariant (see example in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25977631/290085)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **XSD 1.0**, you'll have to check such a constraint in code.

With **XSD 1.1**, you can use [`xs:assert`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) to state count invariants:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.1"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Element_A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Element_B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Element_C">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Element_D"/>
                    <xs:element name="Element_E"/>
                    <xs:element name="Element_F"/>
                    <xs:element name="Element_G"/>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:assert test="    count(Element_E) = 1
                                   and count(Element_F) = 1
                                   and count(Element_G) = 1"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Code it is :). Thanks kjhughes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into **maxOccurs** ?

```
<xsd:element ref="Element_E" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp